# Zero out column of multidimensional list

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I've been beating my head against a wall trying to figure this out. Trying to avoid for loops, I want to zero out a column that already has values.

Here is a snippet of the data in the list l:

```
[[1]]
                      name team bye fpts
1             Arian Foster  Hou   7  315
2          Adrian Peterson  Min   4  233
3           Jamaal Charles   KC   4  225
4            Peyton Hillis  Cle   8  223
5            Chris Johnson  Ten   9  218 

[[2]]
                      name team bye fpts
1                 Ray Rice  Bal   5  287 
2             LeSean McCoy  Phi   7  271
3       Maurice Jones-Drew  Jax   9  250
4             Arian Foster  Hou  11  241
5           Michael Turner  Atl   8  205

[[3]]
                      name team bye fpts
1          Adrian Peterson  Min  11  299
2             Arian Foster  Hou   8  250
3              Doug Martin   TB   5  249
4           Marshawn Lynch  Sea  11  236
5            Alfred Morris  Was  10  233
```

Here is the code I am trying to execute

```
  ldims = length(l) # where l is a 7 dimension list

  # clear out all fpts values 
  for(i in 1:ldims)
  {
     l[[i]][, 4] = 0.0 # for all elements in column 4, assign it zero
  }
```

And here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
[[1]]
                      name team bye fpts
1             Arian Foster  Hou   7  0
2          Adrian Peterson  Min   4  0
3           Jamaal Charles   KC   4  0
4            Peyton Hillis  Cle   8  0
5            Chris Johnson  Ten   9  0 

[[2]]
                      name team bye fpts
1                 Ray Rice  Bal   5  0 
2             LeSean McCoy  Phi   7  0
3       Maurice Jones-Drew  Jax   9  0
4             Arian Foster  Hou  11  0
5           Michael Turner  Atl   8  0

[[3]]
                      name team bye fpts
1          Adrian Peterson  Min  11  0
2             Arian Foster  Hou   8  0
3              Doug Martin   TB   5  0
4           Marshawn Lynch  Sea  11  0
5            Alfred Morris  Was  10  0
```

What I have done is iterate through the dimensions of the list and applying 0 to the entire column. This works but seems clunky for R (I come from a C-language background). I feel like there should a way to do this with `apply` or `lapply`.

Comment: can you show what is your data like?

Comment: A `for` loop should be fine for this. The *apply functions return copies and if you want to modify the original, you might as well do it directly in a `for` loop. If you want additional help, you should provide a reproducible example. Either construct it from scratch or use `dput` on an existing object and copy/paste the output into your question.

Comment: You could do `l = lapply(l, function(x) { x[, 4] = 0; return(x)})` but as Imo says might that may perform worse than your for loop. `lapply` is just hiding a loop from the syntax you type (and in this case, making a copy). I'd test it if your example was reproducible...

Comment: @Hardikgupta I attached a snippet of the list I am using and the output I am trying to achieve

Comment: each is a data frame in the list?

Comment: Yes, it is 3 dimensions deep.

Comment: Why not have a single dataframe with an extra column indicating the group (1 to 3)? Then the task at hand becomes trivial, and most common tasks will be much easier as well.

Comment: @antoine-sac Interesting Idea, the reason I did it this way is because I want to look at yearly stats of players independent of other years. Then I want to average the best player of every year, then second best, so I can have tiers for decision boundaries. This is very easily done using mean(as.double(lapply(l, '[[', rank, 4)))/16, where rank is the rank in the season and 16 is the total number of games played. I could do it your way but I would have to be cognizant of the indexing value.

Comment: `mean(as.double(lapply(l, '[[', rank, 4)))/16` does not sound "very easy" to me :) Also if each list element is a year, then you should really have a single data.frame with a column "year". You can still easily do average by year, etc.

Comment: Maybe easy wasn't the best word, but elegant?

Comment: You may want to look up http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/ to check out how to manipulate data.frames.

Answer (score 0):

Replicating your data structure, replacing your inner data.frames with mtcars:

```
L <- list(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars)
```

First turning the list into a single data.frame with a new variable "group" indicating the originating list element.

```
df <- dplyr::bind_rows(L, .id="group")
```

You can then simply set the column to `0.0`:

```
df$mpg <- 0.0
```

Or using dplyr:

```
df <- mutate(df, mpg=0.0)
```

Using a single data.frame is helpful to perform most common tasks/analysis. You can easily do group-wise analysis using the `group` column (using e.g. `dplyr`'s `group_by` and `summarize`).